# How to compare DataTable and string if it exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a data in my table `Brands` that contains `Smart` or `Sun`. The program uploads a csv but before uploading the csv the program needs to check in the column `Brands` of csv if there is a row that contains not either `Smart` or `Sun` so far I did this

```
DataTable dtCsv = new DataTable();
int matchCount;
using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(fs), true))
     {
         dtCsv.Load(csvReader);
     }

if (dtCsv.Select("BATCH_LEADS<>'" + batch.LeadBatch + "'").Count() != 0) return false;

foreach (Brand brands in BrandList)
{
      matchCount = dtCsv.Select("BRAND<>'" + brands.BrandName + "'").Count();
}
```

but I know what im doing is wrong because the `matchCount` will contain the unmatch count in the column. Please help me. Im using `C#` and this is a `asp.net MVC` project

Comment: This is a really bad question.  Please read the FAQ to find out how to write good questions - questions we can help you with.

Comment: The CSV content is still unclear - please add more details to reveal mistakes of given code. Read [ask] & [mcve] to find out what you need to include with.

Comment: @SamAxe sorry my explanation was deleted by me.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto please re-read my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I am not aware that data table uses query like statement. So I did it like this. And it works well for me

```
int matchCount = 0;
using (MappingDBUnitOfWork muw = new MappingDBUnitOfWork(new MappingEntities()))
            {
                var BrandList = muw.BrandRepository.GetAll();
                foreach (Brand brands in BrandList)
                {
                    matchCount += dtCsv.Select("BRAND ='" + brands.BrandName + "'").Count();
                }
            }

            if (matchCount != dtCsv.Rows.Count) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is not the exact code , but i hope it will show the  right direction. That is Once we got the data from the csv as a datatable , we can also check like below:

**Sample code:**

```
DataTable dtCsv = new DataTable();
int matchCount;
using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(fs), true))
     {
         dtCsv.Load(csvReader);
     }

  for (int rowcount = 0; rowcount < dtCsv.Rows.Count; rowcount++)
   {
          //brands is the column name in excel
         if( dtCsv.Rows[rowcount]["brands"].ToString() != "sum" || dtCsv.Rows[rowcount]["brands"].ToString() != "smart")
         {

                //do some logic
          }
    }
```

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik